# setViewControllers in didRotateToInterfaceOrientation doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to change my view after the device is rotated. I can't do autorotation support in the view that is drawing because I have custom graphics occurring and it is much easier to reinitialize the view.

The problem I am having is that using `[pageViewController setViewControllers:]` doesn't seem to want to work inside the `didRotateToInterfaceOrientation` block.

Here's the method:

```
- (void) didRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        NSLog(@"%@", pageViewController.viewControllers);
        isLandscape = YES;

        ContentViewController *vc = [self viewControllerAtIndex:currentPage];
        NSLog(@"%@", vc);
        [pageViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:vc] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

        NSLog(@"%@", pageViewController.viewControllers);
    }
}
```

which produces this output:

```
<ContentViewController: 0x74aa8f0>
<ContentViewController: 0xfc0cb00>
<ContentViewController: 0x74aa8f0>
```

Is there some reason I can't change the view controllers inside this method? If so, where should I be doing this change?

EDIT:

I have been able to bypass the issue using `dispatch_async()`, but I'd still like to know why this was a problem in the first place.

Comment: You're missing an end bracket `}` somewhere.  Presumably after `isLandscape = YES;`?

Comment: Not sure if it will help with your current problem, but I would put that in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.